# Write Equations side by side

Tags: math-mode, equations, multicol

My Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=0.7in,hmargin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
    \large
    \begin{eqnarray*}
        x &=& \dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}\\
        &=& \dfrac{5+\sqrt{1}}{2}\\
        &=& \dfrac{5+1}{2}\\
        &=& 3
    \end{eqnarray*}
    \begin{eqnarray*}
        y &=& \dfrac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}\\
        &=& \dfrac{5-\sqrt{1}}{2}\\
        &=& \dfrac{5-1}{2}\\
        &=& 2
    \end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Hi
I need to write above both equations side by side that is horizontally.

Comment: Please don't use `eqnarray*` -- that's outdated. Have  a look on the `alignat*` environment instead

Comment: ok i will use it next time

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `align*` instead, like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=0.7in,hmargin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 x_1 &= \dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2} & x_2 &= \dfrac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2} \\
     &= \dfrac{5+\sqrt{1}}{2}      &     &= \dfrac{5-\sqrt{1}}{2} \\
     &= \dfrac{5+1}{2}             &     &= \dfrac{5-1}{2} \\
     &= 3                          &     &=2
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we use multicol.......?

Comment: @snehal Why do you want that? What's wrong with doing the above?

Comment: there is no problem with given solution but i am looking for alternate ways

Comment: @snehal `multicols` only gives you problems with vertical alignment, and I don't think it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: ok, now i am clear to the problem thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

In this case you can exploit the symmetry between the two parts and use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\openup\jot % make lines a little more far apart
\begin{aligned}[t]
x &= \dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}\\
  &= \dfrac{5+\sqrt{1}}{2}\\
  &= \dfrac{5+1}{2}\\
  &= 3\vphantom{\frac{1}{1}}
\end{aligned}
\qquad\qquad % adjust to suit
\begin{aligned}[t]
y &= \dfrac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}\\
  &= \dfrac{5-\sqrt{1}}{2}\\
  &= \dfrac{5-1}{2}\\
  &= 2\vphantom{\frac{1}{1}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I removed everything that was inessential for the particular task and used a couple of tricks: with `\openup\jot` the lines are a bit more spread out; with the `\vphantom` we ensure the equals signs are vertically spaced the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the two formulas in `minipage`s

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=0.7in,hmargin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
    \large
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
        x &= \dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}\\
        &= \dfrac{5+\sqrt{1}}{2}\\
        &= \dfrac{5+1}{2}\\
        &= 3
    \end{align*}      
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
        y &= \dfrac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}\\
        &= \dfrac{5-\sqrt{1}}{2}\\
        &= \dfrac{5-1}{2}\\
        &= 2
    \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]